# highcharts - avoid repeating same date on x axis with different time

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create an X axis with datetime type where every unique date is displayed along with time and subsequent date label displays just time instead of repeating the same date again.

For Ex: If the dates are like, 01/Jan/1970 10:00 AM, 01/Jan/1970 10:30 AM, 01/Jan/1970 11:00 AM etc, i would like to display the x-axis lables like:

01/Jan/1970 10:00 AM, 10:30 AM, 11:00 AM

How can i do that?

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%b/%Y %H:%M %p', this.value);
            }
        }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]
        }, {
            data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1]
        }]
    });
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-pointstart-datetime/)

Comment: Your sample doesn't show the behavior you describe. When does this happen? In my experience it will either just show date (when it changed) or the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can put if condition with start date in label formatter function :

```
labels: {
    formatter: function () {
              if (this.value == Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1))
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d/%b/%Y %H:%M %p', this.value);      
              else 
                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M %p', this.value);
               }
 }
```

Check the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azharamin/y0nyr2wy/)

Comment: Azhar: Your example works fine. However if i comment/remove the PlotOptions block, the first label also is shown as time and date is missing. I am exactly getting the same issue in my app. I can not set the plot options in my case and i need exactly same behaviour when the plot options is present.

Comment: i mean to say i dont want to configure pointStart/pointInterval as i expect the chart picks up/decides the pointStart from my data.

Comment: here is the example that i am trying and is working fine on Fiddle but in my application, it shows all Time labels. What could be the issue?

http://jsfiddle.net/y0nyr2wy/2/

Comment: Maybe your application code overwrite something, do you receive any errors ? How we can replicate your issue as live demo?

Comment: Here is my configuration. I found what exactly causing the issue. Appreciate how to solve this. Here is the Fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/y0nyr2wy/3/

Uncommenting line 21 causes the date being removed from first label.

Comment: In the labels you have flag: isFirst, so simpler is usign this instead of jquery. Fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y0nyr2wy/4/

Comment: Sebastian - It solved 50% of the problem. Thanks. However i want to repeat each new date for first label. In the updated example, last 3 labels belong to new date but only time is displayed. I want date to be displayed for the very first label when date changes.

http://jsfiddle.net/y0nyr2wy/5/

I tried both approaches in "formatter" but not working.

Comment: Can anyone help me solving my issue?

Comment: @Mohan please go through this update fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/azharamin/y0nyr2wy/6/

Comment: @Mohammed - It worked great..Appreciate all your help. It solved my issue now. Thanks again